# Flatten a long dataset, inserting an indicator if at least one non-missing value

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have a relatively large (~100,000 rows) dataset, with multiple rows for each individual. Individuals are identified by 'id'.  My goal is to convert to a data frame or data.table with a single row per individual.
For each column, ie. wt:sat, each row would contain an indicator, signifying whether there was at least one non-missing instance of each variable for a given individual.

For example, given the data below:

```
 dat <- structure(list(id = c(386L, 386L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 2794L, 
2732L, 2732L), wt = c(56.7, 56.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 36.3, 36.3), 
    pain = c(NA, NA, 8L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, NA), sbp = c(120L, NA, 
    125L, 125L, NA, NA, 120L, 120L), dbp = c(60L, NA, 81L, 81L, 
    NA, NA, 67L, 67L), hr = c(84L, NA, 100L, 100L, NA, NA, 120L, 
    120L), rr = c(16L, NA, 18L, 18L, NA, NA, 24L, 24L), sat = c(93L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 99L, 99L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to produce:

[image]

Comment: Is it just my computer or did you forget to add the desired output?

Comment: Desired output was added as a png, <https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFxum.png>

Comment: Thus far, I can generate (repeated) rows for each column as follows:dat %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(wt = if_else(all(is.na(wt)), 0, 1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

A `tidyverse` solution:

```
dat %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_all(~as.numeric(any(. > 0)))

# A tibble: 3 x 8
     id    wt  pain   sbp   dbp    hr    rr   sat
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   386     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
2  2732     1     0     1     1     1     1     1
3  2794     0     1     1     1     1     1     0
```

A `data.table` solution:

```
dat2 <- dat
setDT(dat2)
dat2[is.na(dat2)] <- 0
dat2[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(any(x > 0))), id]
```

Or, a more concise `data.table` solution from @markus (thank you), and you can use `!is.na(.)` in lieu of `. > 0` for the other solutions as well (and you do not have to replace `NA` with `0`):

```
cols <- names(dat)[-1];
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(any(!is.na(x)))), .SDcol = cols, by = id]

     id wt pain sbp dbp hr rr sat
1:  386  1    0   1   1  1  1   1
2: 2794  0    1   1   1  1  1   0
3: 2732  1    0   1   1  1  1   1
```

Comment: @markus, just added it. Very simple code. I am just starting to write work more in `data.table` so I am still learning best-practices. Here, is it still advantageous / a good idea to exclude the `id` columns from `.SD` if it is being used as the grouping variable?

Comment: Sry for the late reply. Yes, you are right - there is no need to exclude `id` when it's used as a grouping variable.

Answer (score 2):

An option in `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ id, replace(dat, is.na(dat), 0), FUN =
      function(x) as.integer(any(x > 0)), na.action = NULL)
#    id wt pain sbp dbp hr rr sat
#1  386  1    0   1   1  1  1   1
#2 2732  1    0   1   1  1  1   1
#3 2794  0    1   1   1  1  1   0
```

---

Or with `rowsum` from `base R`

```
+(rowsum(+(dat[-1]  > 0 & !is.na(dat[-1])), dat$id) != 0)
#     wt pain sbp dbp hr rr sat
#386   1    0   1   1  1  1   1
#2732  1    0   1   1  1  1   1
#2794  0    1   1   1  1  1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id) %>% 
  mutate(value2 = if_else(is.na(value), 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(id, key) %>% 
  summarise(value2 = max(value2)) %>% 
  spread(key, value2)
```

In short:

- convert to long format
- create indicator variable
- summarise over `id` and `key`
- reconvert to wide format